# Advanced XPath Expression Need

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath

I am trying to parse a very unclear and not well formatted HTML page to fetch some information.

Here is one example of this Page:

```
<form name="Form_Envio" method="post" action="/protesto/ieptb/SP/busca/SinProtIF15.php">
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial"><input type="button" value="NOVA PESQUISA" id="nvp" onMouseOver="hand(this);" onmouseout="pointer(this);" onClick="limpa_jucka()"></font>
== Content
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#FF0000"><p align="center">IMPORTANTE: ESTA INFORMAÇÃO REFERE-SE APENAS A PESQUISA,<br>NÃO TENDO VALIDADE DE CERTIDÃO</font>
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><p align="left">Pesquisa efetuada em: </font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial"  color="#003399"><b>04/01/2012</b></font>
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"> &agrave;s </font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><b>14:15:03</b></font>
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;N. </font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><b>22620645</b> <br></font>
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399">RETROATIVO A CINCO ANOS AT&Eacute;    </font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><b>26/12/2011</b><br></font>
<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><b>Pesquise tambem pelo R.G.</b>  <br>Para o </font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><b>C.P.F. N. 000.923.266-41</b></font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><br>NAS CIDADES PARTICIPANTES </font></font>
<font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#003399"><br></font>
<font style="font:bold small-caps 9pt/11pt sans-serif,arial;color:#003399;">CONSTA(M) PROTESTO(S) POR FALTA DE PAGAMENTO, NO(S) SEGUINTE(S) TABELIONATO(S)<br><br></b></font></font>
== Next line is the start of useful information
<font style="font:bold 10pt/12pt sans-serif,arial;color:#003399;"><b>TABELIÃO DE NOTAS E DE PROTESTO DE LETRAS E TÍTULOS</b></font>
<font style="font:8pt/9pt sans-serif,arial;color:#003399;"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AV. VEREADOR JOÃO FERNANDES DA SILVA, 180 - Telefone: 11 4640-4542 fax 4642-3285<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VILA VIRGINIA - ITAQUAQUECETUBA - SP<br><br></font>
== End of useful information
<font size="2" face="Times,Verdana,Arial" color="#003399"><table border="0" bgcolor="#00AADD" width="100%"><tr align="left" id="tpc" onmouseover="change_hand(this);" onmouseup="put_s25();">
<font style="font:bold 8pt/9pt sans-serif,arial;color:#000000;">Caso deseje mais informa&ccedil;&otilde;es sobre credor, valor e etc. </font><br>
<font style="font:bold 11pt/13pt sans-serif,arial;color:#0000FF;">CLIQUE AQUI, </font>
<font style="font:bold 8pt/9pt sans-serif,arial;color:#000000;">para requerer sua Certid&atilde;o de Protesto.</tr></table></font>
== End of Content
```

Having the HTML above I already managed to fetch the Date, Hour, ID of the Query and Document number used in the query (this information can be found in the lines in which the `<font>` attribute have `size="2"`).

This is the XPath i used to get the information I needed:

```
HtmlNodeCollection tmpNodes = documentModel.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//font[@size='2']/b");
```

My next step is to retrieve the information found in between the `==Useful Information` markup. In this case, it would be two strings :

1. `TABELIÃO DE NOTAS E DE PROTESTO DE LETRAS E TÍTULOS`
2. `AV. VEREADOR JOÃO FERNANDES DA SILVA, 180 - Telefone: 11 4640-4542 fax 4642-3285<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VILA VIRGINIA - ITAQUAQUECETUBA - SP` (I can parse them after)

** Question: **

How do i get this information ? Can i use XPath using the @Style Attribute ? I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need some way to uniquely identify those elements. For example:

```
//font[not(@size) and contains(@style, '#003399') 
                  and not(contains(@style, 'small-caps'))]
```

This selects the `font` elements without a `size` attribute and having a `style` attribute that contains the text `#003399`, but not the text `small-caps` (in an effort to exclude earlier `font` elements that meet the other criteria).

Note that this returns the `font` elements directly, not their children.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.. basically remove the "@" in the size

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);     
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes"//font[size='2']/b");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  Console.WriteLine(xn.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but it does not solve my problem since the info i want are the dones without the 'size=2' attribute. Basicaly, those with @Style .

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found what i wanted by using these XPaths:

```
//font[@style='font:bold 10pt/12pt sans-serif,arial;color:#003399;']/b
```

and

```
//font[@style="font:8pt/9pt sans-serif,arial;color:#003399;']
```

Thanks !

Comment: Just be careful to note that you might not always see the `style` contents in the same order, so a literal match could fail. That's why I went for the `contains` approach in my answer.

Comment: Your aproach is indeed better than mine, thanks for taking time to answer me.

I will change what i've done to implement your XPath